# How to kill a process within spacemacs

Tags: emacs, kill-process, spacemacs

I recently felt the need to work with Spacemacs for my erlang/elixir projects.
(was coding Erlang on eclipse).

Now i'm feeling a bit more comfortable with Spacemacs, i have a question regarding how to deal with processes.

I made a mistake on my code and had an infinite loop.
I killed it on console but i was wondering how to do the same thing within spacemacs.
I've found that **SPC a p** gave me the possibility to list all the running processes.

Can please someone explain me (i'm a complete beginner on spacemacs/emacs) if it is possible to kill a running process within this menu ?

Regards

Pierre

Comment: Do you mean kill buffer? You can try with `space b d ` and `y` to confirm or run command `:bd` to kill current buffer.

Comment: To begin with, we have `M-x list-processes`, that you may have invoked with your spacemacs keys…

Comment: Thanks for replying ! I do have the processes list, please find the screenshot below : http://i613.photobucket.com/albums/tt214/pierrelaurent62/spacemacs_zpsjoncf0xw.png
As you may see, processes are on the right (you were rigth Ehvince), is there a proper way to kill the first one for example ? I can't find any key combination inside spacemacs.

I've tried 'space b d', it close the buffer but it doesn't seems to kill the process as it is still running. ( i can still see it with a ps -ef)

Comment: I don't know and I'm looking for it for some time too !

Comment: Looks like we find the processes of `list-processes` into `M-x proced`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`M-x proced`

Choose your line and then `k`

Comment: Any idea how to do this in evil mode? k just navigates to next process....

Comment: You can use `SPC ?` to get all the commands. Proced is `SPC a P`

Answer (score 3):

In Spacemacs, `SPC a p`, which runs the command `list-processes`, opens a buffer showing only those processes started by Spacemacs.

The list process buffer is evilified, so `j` and `k` navigate the list of processes,

`d` in the list process buffer will immediately delete the process under the cursor (no prompt to confirm is given, so ensure its what you want to do).

`q` will quit the process list and close the buffer.

Note: `SPC a P` will list all operating system processes, not just those spawned by Spacemacs.

Reference: https://practicalli.github.io/spacemacs/install-spacemacs/troubleshooting.html